# ffmpeg add two subtitle files to the same mp4

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have two subtitle tracks files: `spanish.ass` and `english.ass`. I want to insert them into an mp4.  I can do one or the other but not both.

I am using:

```
ffmpeg -i Clean.mp4 -i spanish.ass -c:s mov_text -c:v copy -c:a copy -metadata:s:s:0 language=spa With1CC.mp4
```

and then

```
ffmpeg -i With1CC.mp4 -i english.ass -c:s mov_text -c:v copy -c:a copy -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng With2CC.mp4
```

...but while the first statement successfully inserts the Spanish subtitles, the second just changes the visual name of the track to read English. The actual English track is not actually inserted as a second track

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i Clean.mp4 -i spanish.ass -i english.ass -c:s mov_text -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1 -map 2 -metadata:s:s:0 language=spa -metadata:s:s:1 language=eng With2CC.mp4
```